# Why with two classes, LDA gives only one dimension?

Tags: r, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have a dataset with 291 rows and 18 columns.

I am a beginner at performing linear discriminant analysis and I want to apply LDA with the MASS  package in R. After making the data partition of my data, I am usisng the below script.

```
library(MASS)
# Fit the model
lda.model <- lda(Outcome~., data = train.data,CV = FALSE)
lda.model
```

Where Outcome is the response variable and takes two factors Win or Loss.
I want to know if there is any predefined functions to add to my code to be optimized since I get only one dimension for the Coefficients of linear discriminants output and no proportion of trace as shown in the [image: LDA Output].

Why would this not been shown with my own code?

Answer (score 0):

You've got one dimension because you're response variable takes two values.
The output you've got looks like this :
[have a look at this picture][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay4xs.png

In other terms you've got the c values.